# Cant get GTK Themes to run on OS X

Tags: macos, gtk, themes, homebrew

I am running OSX Mavericks with Homebrew and I am trying to get a GTK theme running which requires the murrine engine.

I have the following packages installed:

gtk+
gtk+3
gtk-chtheme
gtk-engines
gtk-murrine-engine
gtkmm

However gtk-chtheme does not find any GTK themes other than Raleigh.

When I tried to use a theme requiring the Murrine engine, each GTK application told me that the murrine engine was not in gtk's module_path

I set GTK_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gtk-2.0 like the post installation of the above packages suggested.

Still no success.

I can't even set a GTK theme using ~/.gtkrc-2.0 in which I tried to set a GTK-theme like so:

include "/usr/local/Cellar/gtk-engines/2.20.2/share/themes/Clearlooks/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the application gtk or gtk3 based? And does that app have a name?

Comment: pretty sure gtk2-based. (inkscape, gtk-chtheme). anyway: i got a decent gtk-theme to work, which somehow used an engine but resides in my home folder and not in homebrew's cellar.

Answer (score 5):

Install gtk via brew. Then place themes in ~/.themes/ folder:

```
$ mkdir ~/.themes/ && cd $_
$ curl http://putty.org.ru/files/LionGTKTheme.tar.gz | tar -zx
$ cd ~
```

Then install gtk-chtheme tool:

```
$ brew install gtk-chtheme
```

Launch it and voila:

[image: gtk-chtheme]

Comment: You may need to use `brew install homebrew/gui/gtk-chtheme`, at least that's what I had to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to get this to work. No matter what I do the themes simply don't show up in gtk-chtheme. Thankfully I was able to get my own GTK app to use a custom by specifying `GTK2_RC_FILES=<path_to_gtkrc_of_theme>` for example `GTK2_RC_FILES=/Users/dom/.themes/OSX-Yosemite/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`, before the binary.


You must also be careful about GTK 2 engines, some themes will not work without them. I installed `gnome-themes-standard` using brew which installed some engines I believe.

Comment: There's only Raleigh theme in the list, other themes are not listed.GTK2_RC_FILES= also doesn't work with High Sierra.

Comment: @maxagaz other themes you need to install by yourself.

Comment: I have installed Gnome-OSX-V-HSierra-1-3-2 theme in ~/.themes, but it doesn't appear in the list of gtk-chtheme.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x   15 maxagaz  staff   480B Dec  1 08:08 0nyX/
drwxr-xr-x   10 maxagaz  staff   320B Dec 20 14:43 0nyX-Suite-master/
drwxr-xr-x    4 maxagaz  staff   128B Sep 30 16:22 Gnome-OSX-V-HSierra-1-3-2/
drwxr-xr-x@  22 maxagaz  staff   704B Jan  9  2017 OSX-Arc-White/

Comment: Ok, try to place all these dirs https://github.com/paullinuxthemer/Gnome-OSX/tree/master/src to `~/.themes `. Launch `gtk-chtheme` **not** from `~/.themes` dir.

Answer (score 2):

as the README says:

> This will allow GTK+ to find the newly installed theme engines. To use the
>   default themes (installed into `$prefix/share/themes`), you'll need to copy or
>   link them into your `~/.themes` directory.

the themes should be located in `/usr/local/Cellar/gtk-engines/2.20.2/share/themes`